# Proving Periodicity of a Function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, periodic-functions

> How to prove that a function $f(x)$ symmetric with respect to the lines $x=a$ and $x=b$, where $a\neq b$) is periodic?

Any help or hint is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$f(x)=f(a-x),\tag{1}$$
and
$$f(t)=f(b-t).\tag{2}$$
By putting $t = b-a+x$ in $(2)$, we get
$$f(x+(b-a))=f(a-x)=f(x).\tag{3}$$